# vfork() with gcc -O2 seems to have a wrong result.

Tags: c, linux, gcc, vfork

I took the code from APUE. In Ubuntu 12.04 if I use gcc without any optimization, I will get the results same as the book's:

```
pid = 4122, glob = 7, var = 89.
```

If I use gcc -O2, then the var will be 88.
Is this because the gcc optimization will do something with vfork()?

```
#include "apue.h"

int glob = 6;

int
main(void)
{
  int var;
  pid_t pid;
  var = 88;
  printf("before vfork\n");
  if ((pid = vfork()) < 0) {
    err_sys("vfork error");
  } else if ( pid ==0) {
    glob++;
    var++;
    _exit(0);
  }

  printf("pid = %d, glob = %d, var = %d\n", getpid(), glob, var);
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Consider `vfork` as a *deprecated* syscall (just use `fork`). I'm not sure your code is valid.... Also, use `gcc -S -fverbose-asm -O2` to get the generated assembly code (perhaps even `-fdump-tree-all` which generates hundreds of dump files)...

Comment: Thanks, I generated the assembly code, and get `addl $1, glob(%rip) call _exit`, seems the `var++` is missing somehow.

Comment: My understanding is that your code is not valid and GCC is permitted to optimize like it does.

Comment: I don't think the code is invalid. Even use the `-Wall` option, the gcc will compile successful without any warning for both with `-O2` and without `-O2`.

Comment: The code *is invalid*. And detecting [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) is *in general* an [undecidable problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem) equivalent to the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). So you can't expect `gcc` to *always* warn you wisely!

Comment: The point of using vfork() rather than fork() is for efficiency when doing a fork() immediately followed by an exec().  If you aren't immediately doing an exec(), you should be using fork().  (immediately meaning you don't do other things first)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the specification those two lines in the child's code

```
    glob++;
    var++;
```

provoke undefined behaviuor.

From [Linux `man vfork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html):

> ([From POSIX.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/vfork.html)) [...] the behavior is undefined if the process created by
>          vfork() either modifies any data other than a variable of type pid_t
>          used to store the return value from vfork() [...]

It might be worth noting that `vfork()` was "*marked obsolescent*" in the previous version of POSIX (see POSIX link above) and was [removed from POSIX with Issue 7 (POSIX.1-2008)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xsh_chap03.html):

> Applications are recommended to use the [fork()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) function instead of this function.
>
> The vfork() function was previously under-specified.

Comment: So `gcc` may optimize like it does!

Comment: Absolutly. @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: @ZongyuanGU: note that APUE mentions in the paragraphs before the example program that `vfork()` leads to undefined results if the child modifies any data. The example is meant to show that `vfork()` behavior can differ form `fork()` (in that the child can modify the state of the parent).  However, APUE doesn't make it very clear that the example program can show different behavior than in their running of the program.